# APA reference for uppercase word in title of book

Tags: writing-style, citation, style-manuals, reference

I need to complete references for an assignment in APA format, but one of the books has an uppercase word in it and I'm not sure if it should remain uppercase or be changed to lowercase:

The SAGE Handbook of Grounded Theory, by Antony Bryant and Kathy Charmaz

In this context, SAGE is the name of the publishing company (https://sagepub.com) and the origin of the name is that it comes from the first two letters of the founders names: SAra Miller and GEorge McCune. So the company name is meant to be capitalised normally.

However, APA states book titles should use sentence-case, with capitalisation for proper nouns... So I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Abbreviations, acronyms, brand names, names of companies etc., that are originally written in all capitals should not be changed. You would never say Apa, but APA at all times. HTH.

Comment: I think there are online tools to create bibliographic references in each of the standard styles.